# Names of Processes in Erlang are required to be unforgeable

Tags: erlang

I was reading Joe Armstrong's thesis ***Making reliable distributed systems in the presence of software errors*** where I would like to understand the philosophy around names of processes. It is mentioned

> We require that the names of processes are unforgeable. This means that it
>   should be impossible to guess the name of a process, and thereby interact
>   with that process.

and

> If we do not know the name of a process we cannot
>   interact with it in any way, thus the system is secure. Once the names of
>   processes become widely know the system becomes less secure.

I want to understand that, if finding a process and thus sending message to a process is something which should be done rarely, then what's the purpose of such a process. Also, the processes are in command of what message it can handle and chooses to ignore others anyways. So what's the concern around security.

Can someone please help me understand the underlying thought that I am not able to get.

Thanks

Comment: A much more promising venue for this question is the Erlang mailing list, as it is very likely that you will get an answer from Joe Armstrong himself.